# Error: error getting canonical path to source HTML file "index.html"

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, yew

I am having the following error when I run `trunk serve`

```
Error: error getting canonical path to source HTML file "index.html"

Caused by:
    No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

[image]

Comment: What package are you using with trunk? What is in your `main.rs`? `Cargo.toml`? We need more information.

Comment: I ran it again after a while and it worked. I didn't understand what went wrong